# Get list of pandas dataframe columns based on data type

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

If I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
1. NAME                                     object
2. On_Time                                      object
3. On_Budget                                    object
4. %actual_hr                                  float64
5. Baseline Start Date                  datetime64[ns]
6. Forecast Start Date                  datetime64[ns]
```

I would like to be able to say: for this dataframe, **give me a list of the columns which are of type 'object' or of type 'datetime'**?

I have a function which converts numbers ('float64') to two decimal places, and I would like to use this list of dataframe columns, of a particular type, and run it through this function to convert them all to 2dp.

Maybe something like:

```
For c in col_list: if c.dtype = "Something"
list[]
List.append(c)?
```

Comment: When I came to this question, I was looking for a way to create exactly the list in the top. `df.dtypes` does that.

Comment: Visitors may also be interested in this different but related question on how to find all object types *within each column*: [How could I detect subtypes in pandas object columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817742/how-could-i-detect-subtypes-in-pandas-object-columns).

Answer (score 353, accepted):

If you want a list of columns of a certain type, you can use `groupby`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.3456, 'c', 'd', 78]], columns=list("ABCDE"))
>>> df
   A       B  C  D   E
0  1  2.3456  c  d  78

[1 rows x 5 columns]
>>> df.dtypes
A      int64
B    float64
C     object
D     object
E      int64
dtype: object
>>> g = df.columns.to_series().groupby(df.dtypes).groups
>>> g
{dtype('int64'): ['A', 'E'], dtype('float64'): ['B'], dtype('O'): ['C', 'D']}
>>> {k.name: v for k, v in g.items()}
{'object': ['C', 'D'], 'int64': ['A', 'E'], 'float64': ['B']}
```

Answer (score 155):

As of pandas v0.14.1, you can utilize [`select_dtypes()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select columns by dtype

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': list('abcdef'),
    'On_Time': [True, False] * 3,
    'On_Budget': [False, True] * 3})

In [3]: df.select_dtypes(include=['bool'])
Out[3]:
  On_Budget On_Time
0     False    True
1      True   False
2     False    True
3      True   False
4     False    True
5      True   False

In [4]: mylist = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['bool']).columns)

In [5]: mylist
Out[5]: ['On_Budget', 'On_Time']
```

Answer (score 50):

```
list(df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns)
```

This should do the trick

Answer (score 42):

Using `dtype` will give you desired column's data type:

```
dataframe['column1'].dtype
```

---

**if you want to know data types of all the column at once**, you can use plural of `dtype` as [dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
dataframe.dtypes
```

Answer (score 29):

You can use boolean mask on the dtypes attribute:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.3456, 'c']])

In [12]: df.dtypes
Out[12]: 
0      int64
1    float64
2     object
dtype: object

In [13]: msk = df.dtypes == np.float64  # or object, etc.

In [14]: msk
Out[14]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

You can look at just those columns with the desired dtype:

```
In [15]: df.loc[:, msk]
Out[15]: 
        1
0  2.3456
```

Now you can use round (or whatever) and assign it back:

```
In [16]: np.round(df.loc[:, msk], 2)
Out[16]: 
      1
0  2.35

In [17]: df.loc[:, msk] = np.round(df.loc[:, msk], 2)

In [18]: df
Out[18]: 
   0     1  2
0  1  2.35  c
```

Answer (score 11):

use `df.info(verbose=True)` where `df` is a pandas datafarme, by default `verbose=False`

Answer (score 11):

The most direct way to get a list of columns of certain dtype e.g. 'object':

```
df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
```

For example:

```
>>df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.3456, 'c', 'd', 78]], columns=list("ABCDE"))
>>df.dtypes

A      int64
B    float64
C     object
D     object
E      int64
dtype: object
```

To get all 'object' dtype columns:

```
>>df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns

Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

For just the list:

```
>>list(df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns)

['C', 'D']
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a list of only the object columns you could do:

```
non_numerics = [x for x in df.columns \
                if not (df[x].dtype == np.float64 \
                        or df[x].dtype == np.int64)]
```

and then if you want to get another list of only the numerics:

```
numerics = [x for x in df.columns if x not in non_numerics]
```

Answer (score 4):

If after 6 years you still have the issue, this should solve it :)

```
cols = [c for c in df.columns if df[c].dtype in ['object', 'datetime64[ns]']]
```

Answer (score 1):

**I came up with this three liner**.

Essentially, here's what it does:

1. Fetch the column names and their respective data types.
2. I am optionally outputting it to a csv.

---

```
inp = pd.read_csv('filename.csv') # read input. Add read_csv arguments as needed
columns = pd.DataFrame({'column_names': inp.columns, 'datatypes': inp.dtypes})
columns.to_csv(inp+'columns_list.csv', encoding='utf-8') # encoding is optional
```

This made my life much easier in trying to **generate schemas** on the fly. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'float': [1.0],
                   'int': [1],
                   'bool_1': [False],
                   'datetime': [pd.Timestamp('20180310')],
                   'bool_2': [True],
                   'string': ['foo']})
df.dtypes

# float              float64
# int                  int64
# bool_1                bool
# datetime    datetime64[ns]
# bool_2                bool
# string              object
# dtype: object


[column for column, is_type in (df.dtypes==bool).items() if is_type]
# ['bool_1', 'bool_2']
```

Answer (score 0):

for yoshiserry;

```
def col_types(x,pd):
    dtypes=x.dtypes
    dtypes_col=dtypes.index
    dtypes_type=dtypes.value
    column_types=dict(zip(dtypes_col,dtypes_type))
    return column_types
```

Answer (score 0):

I use infer_objects()

> Docstring: Attempt to infer better dtypes for object columns.
>
> Attempts soft conversion of object-dtyped columns, leaving non-object
>   and unconvertible columns unchanged. The inference rules are the same
>   as during normal Series/DataFrame construction.

`df.infer_objects().dtypes`

Answer (score 0):

Many of the posted solutions use df.select_dtypes which unnecessarily creates a temporary intermediate dataframe.   If all you want is "a list of the columns which are of" non-numeric (not float32/int64/complex128/etc.) types, just do one of these (remove the "not" if you *do* want *just* the numeric types):

```
import numpy as np
[c for c in df.columns if not np.issubdtype(df[c].dtype, np.number)]
```

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
[c for c in df.columns if not is_numeric_dtype(c)]
```

Note: if you want to distinguish floating (float32/float64) from integer and complex then you could use np.floating instead of np.number in the first of the two solutions above or in the first of the two just below.

If you want the result to be a pd.Index rather than just a list of column name strings as above, here are two ways (first is based on @juanpa.arrivillaga):

```
import numpy as np
df.columns[[not np.issubdtype(dt, np.number) for dt in df.dtypes]]
```

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
df.columns[[not is_numeric_dtype(c) for c in df.columns]]
```

Some other methods may consider a bool column to be numeric, but the solutions above do not (tested with numpy 1.22.3 / pandas 1.4.2).