# Apply one hot encoding in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-mining, categorical-data

How to apply one hot encoding only to the columns having numeric categorical values. I want to modify the same dataframe. Dataframe has other features with string values. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a dataframe what you can do is use the `pd.get_dummies(...)` method.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

>>> pd.get_dummies(s)
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

You can checkout the [Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) for more.

There is also an optional `columns` argument which takes in a list of the columns to turn into dummies.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470690/get-list-of-pandas-dataframe-columns-based-on-data-type) is an SO question pertaining to how to get a list of columns and types.