# Pandas DataFrame - repeat rows and calculate rolling mean for column of type float64

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to add additional rows to Pandas DataFrame. However, for columns that are of the type `float64`, I need to calculate previous 3-observation rolling mean instead of simply repeat. In the below DataFrame `Score1` column is of the type `float64`.

For the `month` column, I need to increment by +1.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Month' : [1,2,3],
                   'Year' : [2021,2021,2021],
                   'Label' : ['A','A','A'],
                   'Score1' : [1.1,1.2,1.3]
                 })
```

How do I incorporate the rolling mean calculation with replicating rows? Expected output:

```
Month Year Label Score1
1     2021   A    1.1
2     2021   A    1.2
3     2021   A    1.3
4     2021   A    1.2
5     2021   A    1.2
6     2021   A    1.2
```

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Compute the mean of all the rows, then add a row with that mean, then compute the mean all the rows including the new row, then add it, etc.? If so, how many times should this be repeated? 3 times, to achieve a DF containing 6 rows?

Comment: For selecting only the float columns `df.select_dtypes(include='float64')`. See [Get list of pandas dataframe columns based on data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470690/get-list-of-pandas-dataframe-columns-based-on-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem correctly, I propose the following solution:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month' : [1,2,3,4],
    'Year' : [2021,2021,2021,2021],
    'Label' : ['A','A','A','A'],
    'Score1' : [1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]
    })

columns = df.dtypes
length = df.shape[0]

# copy last row in new row
df.loc[length] = df.loc[length-1]

for i in range(len(columns.index)):

    if columns.iloc[i] == 'float64':
        # moving average of the last 3 data
        df.loc[length, columns.index[i]] = df.loc[length-3:length-1, columns.index[i]].mean()

    if columns.index[i] == 'Month':
        df.loc[length, columns.index[i]] = df.loc[length-1, columns.index[i]] + 1
```

Here what you do is to copy the last row and replace the values if it is a `float64` type value

Comment: `df.select_dtypes(include='float64')`. That part is a duplicate.

Comment: If I understand correctly is to duplicate a whole row and not only the float64 rows, with the float64 is to make a moving average.